# Getting Pandas Dataframe in correct format for Seaborn swarmplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have data in a CSV file that I would like to plot in a Swarmplot like the 4th example here https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/categorical.html - i.e. with colours denoting groups.

In the CSV file the data is arranged in rows like this:

```
Group,1,1,2,2
Value1,0.5,0.3,0.2,0.1
Value2,1.7,1.3,1.1,1.0
...
```

I want the colours on the swarmplot to be determined by the Group, and there to be a separate plot for each Value.

I have got this far:

```
import pandas as pns
import seaborn as sns
data_in = pns.read_cvs('file.csv',header=None,index_col=0)
data_t = data_in.transpose()
```

At this point my data frame looks like:

```
0 Group Value1 Value2 ...
1     1    0.5    1.7
2     1    0.3    1.3
3     2    0.2    1.1
4     2    0.1    1.0
```

If I then do

```
k = data_t.keys()[[2,3]]
sns.swarmplot(data_t[k])
```

I can pull out the columns I want and get a plot that looks good except for the colours. My problem is that in order to specify the colours using the hue keyword argument, I then have to specify either the 'x' or 'y' arguments as well. I can't figure out how to manipulate my Data Frame into a format where I can specify either of those variables. I think want to get something like this:

```
0 Group   Name Value
1     1 Value1   0.5
2     2 Value1   0.3
3     1 Value2   0.2
4     2 Value2   0.1
```

...

But I can't work out if I want to stack(), use a pivot_table or something else entirely.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to transform the table, you can use `melt`

```
pd.melt(df,id_vars='Group',value_vars=['Value1','Value2'])

Group variable  value
0      1   Value1    0.5
1      1   Value1    0.3
2      2   Value1    0.2
3      2   Value1    0.1
4      1   Value2    1.7
5      1   Value2    1.3
6      2   Value2    1.1
7      2   Value2    1.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. `melt` did the job, and I never would have thought to look for a function called that! In my case I just needed `pns.melt(data_t, id_vars='Group')